# How do you put files in a hdfs directory with space in the directory name?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to put a file in a HDFS directory with the directory name containing space.
The following issue occurs:

Suppose hdfs directory “sub dir1” already exists.
Now I tried to put a file, sub.txt in this directory using following command:

```
hadoop fs -put sub.txt /user/jdutt/TempTesting/output//sub\ dir1/
```

It doesn’t put file in “sub dir1” directory; instead it creates another directory with the name “sub%20dir1” and puts file there.
How to solve this issue?

Comment: What version of Hadoop are you using? Works for me.

Comment: The fact that it's possible to create a directory with `hadoop fs -mkdir "dir with space"` yet populating doesn't work with the same quotation is a bug in hadoop.  I tried a lot of different ways to do the escaping with combinations of `'` and `"`, and none worked.  Weird.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Put file on HDFS with spaces in name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30669210/put-file-on-hdfs-with-spaces-in-name)

Answer (score 4):

Please replace spaces  with %20 ,It may solve your problem .

Answer (score 1):

Please try to run command as

```
hadoop fs -put sub.txt /user/jdutt/TempTesting/output/'sub dir1'/
```

i have tested it on hadoop viersion 1.0.4 and it is working.

Answer (score 0):

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /home/cloudera/Documents/Hadoop/Hive%20Data/empdata hive_data
```

**it's working for me**

Answer (score -2):

```
hadoop fs -put sub.txt "/user/jdutt/TempTesting/output/sub dir1"
```