# Put file on HDFS with spaces in name

Tags: hdfs, hadoop2

I have a file named `file name(1).zip` (with the space and parentheses in it) and I want to put this file on the HDFS. But everytime I try to put it via `hadoop fs -put ...` , I get a an exception.

I have even tried to add quotes around the file and even tried to escape the space and parentheses but it doesn't work.

```
hduser@localhost:/tmp$ hadoop fs -put file\ name\(1\).zip /tmp/one
15/06/05 15:57:46 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
put: unexpected URISyntaxException

hduser@localhost:/tmp$ hadoop fs -put "file\ name\(1\).zip" /tmp/one/
15/06/05 15:59:19 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
put: unexpected URISyntaxException

hduser@localhost:/tmp$ hadoop fs -put "file name(1).zip" /tmp/one/
15/06/05 16:00:36 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
put: unexpected URISyntaxException
```

Is there any work-around to put such files on the HDFS or am I missing something here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most obvious workaround is to rename the file before storing it on HDFS, don't you think?

Comment: Yes that can be a probable solution, but I was hoping for some direct solution instead of a workaround.

Comment: Ended up renaming the file before placing it on the HDFS.

Comment: If the directory contains the space, you may have a bigger problem with this. In that case, it might help to CD, or use one of the workarounds below.

Answer (score 8):

Replace the spaces with %20.

The percent-encoding for space is %20

Use

```
hadoop fs -put first%20name.zip /tmp/one
```

instead of

```
hadoop fs -put first name.zip /tmp/one
```

Comment: I prefer the stdin based solution, as in scripts, this creates a lot of overhead and uncertainty, if you do something with the files locally, before moving them to HDFS. Also, I guess you would have to do full-blow URL-Encoding, to make this work reliably, and not just handle spaces?

Comment: Right. If renaming is an option, I prefer that.
Since the question is to find a way other than renaming, this is an alternate approach to handle this scenario.

Answer (score 4):

HDFS is totally fine with spaces in the file or directory names.

It is the `hdfs` that does not support putting a file from local disk with spaces in its file name. But there is a trick to achieve this ( [reference](https://www.systutorials.com/qa/2394/how-to-put-files-with-spaces-in-names-into-hdfs) ):

```
cat file\ name\(1\).zip | hadoop fs -put - "/tmp/one/file name(1).zip"
```

Hope this helps those that need this.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
fs -put 'file name(1).zip' tmp/one
```

Comment: in your description you say file name(1).log but in code examples file name(1).zip

Comment: Must be a typo, but I get the error either way. Also I get the same error `URISyntaxException ` with what you have suggested.

Answer (score 1):

hadoop fs -get  /landing/novdata/'2017-01-05 - abc def 5H.csv'

See the single quotes around the filename